# How to add Dconf Package to buildroot

Tags: gnome, buildroot, gsettings

I am very new to buildroot. I want to use GSetting in my project. It turns out that **Gsettings** need backend implementation called **GConf** to save the config.

Because of not having this module installed in ROOT-FS, I keep getting this error message when I used the gsettings cmd line utility to read/write the config.

**Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.**

Now the problem is buildroot supports Gsettings and Glib out of the box but not GConf.

Can anyone guide me on how to add this a package to buildroot?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell glib which backend to use for gsettings. It's not entirely clear to me how the default backend is chosen. For sure, you can chose one of the builtin backends with the `GSETTINGS_BACKEND` environment variable. For example, the `keyfile` backend will use an ini-formatted file in `$HOME/.settings/glib-2.0/settings/keyfile`.